# bytes array with image data in RGBA format to file in C# for UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, byte, dji-sdk, rgba

I have a method that receives an array from bytes in RGBA format in a C# UWP, I need to store the image into a file. I lost a lot of time but I have no idea how to start.

I try this:
`BitmapImage bmp = await bytesToImageAsync(data);`
But I don't know if it works and what to do with a BitmapImage.

This is the method:

```
    //Decode data. Do nothing here. This function would return a bytes array with image data in RGBA format.
    async void ReceiveDecodedData(byte[] data, int width, int height)
    {}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You would use the [BitmapEncoder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapEncoder) class to do this. Some samples are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/imaging).  Or you can use a SoftwareBitmap as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/imaging).

```
SoftwareBitmap outputBitmap = SoftwareBitmap.CreateCopyFromBuffer(
    writeableBitmap.PixelBuffer,
    BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
   width,
   height);
```